# Creating SQLite db at runtime without user intervention

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron

I want to create an app (maybe via Electron) which will create an SQLite database file on the users device. I can code the actual creation of the database file and tables in the app no problem, it's just everything I've read says that the sqlite module needs to be installed manually first (npm sqlite etc.). I would like the app to do that at runtime if possible, without user intervention, i.e. when the user installs the app, it installs the SQLite runtime. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible. For security reasons, JavaScript in browsers is not allowed to read or write files without the user selecting the files.

Comment: Ouh ok. I was kinda hoping there was a "<sqlite.h>" type of precompiled header like with C++. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but this advice is wrong, when using Electron. Electron apps run a "main" process using NodeJS, which can use all NPM modules at their descretion. However, I think you may have understood the term "installing the runtime" wrong. You, as a developer, will need to run `npm install sqlite` (or similar). When you package your app, the packaging application *should* take care of SQLite, including all necessary binaries in the package you then distribute. Is that what you want or do you really need to download and use SQLite on the fly, whithout shipping it from the start?

Comment: '...the packaging application should take care of SQLite...' Yes this sounds like what I was hoping for. So when the application creates the sqlite database file, it doesn't return a "sqlite not found" type of error.

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
new sqlite3.Database('./database.db');